# What Are Some Recurring Questions/Themes That Are Explored or Argued for in Renaissance Philosophy?

Tags: self

I suppose this is not necessarily a question, rather I'm looking for inspiration for writing a research paper.

I have been assigned with the task of: "Submit a research paper, using at least 3 secondary sources, on a question raised by renaissance thought"

Initially I was rather motivated since this was an opportunity for me to explore ideas of my own interest, but after contemplating it for a couple of days, I couldn't come up with something to write about! I'm rather new in the studies of renaissance philosophy and have been finding it difficult to think of a question that is commonly explored in renaissance philosophy. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: You can see [Aristotelianism in the Renaissance](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotelianism-renaissance/) as well as [Natural Philosophy in the Renaissance](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natphil-ren/).

Comment: A recent book : Christopher Celenza, [The Intellectual World of the Italian Renaissance : Language, Philosophy, and the Search for Meaning](https://books.google.it/books?id=964_DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2017, Cambridge University Press)